# Angular 2+ Cant access the object in the HTML template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a variable in my component

`property: any;`

I get the complete object  in the console if i do something like this

```
ngOnInit() {
this.propertyService.getProperty(this.propertyId)
  .subscribe(
  prop => console.log(prop)}
```

But when I try the code below and try to render the object in template I get nothing

```
ngOnInit() {
this.propertyService.getProperty(this.propertyId)
  .subscribe(
  prop => this.property = prop}
```

The HTML template is like this

```
 <ul>
       <li>Title: {{property?.title }}</li>
       <li>Price: {{ property?.price}}</li>              
 </ul>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Is your template wired up to the component? Are you using an inline template or an external template?

Comment: try to print `property` in template with json pipe and see what happens

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions .There are no errors in console. I am using external template and is wired up correctly. ( I have checked up with multiple ways). Nothing gets printed when I tried this  {{property | json}}

Answer (score 0):

I made a minor spelling mistake in HTML template
[routerLink]="['/property/edit/', proprety.id] instead of
[routerLink]="['/property/edit/', property.id] 
which was stoping the interpolation from the component in the whole template. Thanks everyone for response.